# Laravel sanctum check if user is authenticated without redirecting

Tags: laravel, authentication, api-design, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Laravel sanctum for my API.

How do I check if the user is authenticated with the sanctum middleware but without redirecting? I want to check if he's authenticated and then do something, if not then do something else, without redirecting or sending the "unauthenticated" message.

Is there a way to do it with sanctum directly or I have to check manually for the token and its expiration?

Comment: you can make something like `$request->session->set('is_sanctrum_redirected', true)` in middleware

Comment: It's a stateless api, no session and i honestly don't know what ``` $request->session->set('is_sanctrum_redirected', true) ``` this means

Comment: hm, if it stateless api - where you can be redirected, huh? in api you will get 401 error, not redirect.

Comment: Yeah i mean i don't want to the request to end and the user to receive a 401 "Unauthenticated" i want to handle if he's not authentiated and send something accordingly

Comment: If you want to rewrite exception message - you can work with this in exception handler.

Comment: Are you asking how to check is the user is authenticated? You can do that most simply via the Auth facade. `Auth::user()` which will return the User model for the authenticated user or it will return null. Obviously you would either do this in your own middleware or a controller. You may also do this from a request object such as that in middleware/controllers `$request->user()` which either returns a model or null if unauthenticated.

Comment: I don't want to write the exception, i want to use Auth::user() or Auth::check but it doesn't work unless i put the middleware "auth:sanctum" to that route, but the thing is that if i put the middleware and the user is not authenticated he'll be rejected with a 401 message, or in my case, there are few PUBLIC objects, i want to check wether the user is logged in or not and send the objects accordingly, not rewrite the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just grab this function from [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L406), paste it in your **"app/Exceptions/Handler.php"** and override as you want.

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    // CUSTOMIZE THE BODY AS YOU WANT..

    return $request->expectsJson()
                ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                : redirect()->guest($exception->redirectTo() ?? route('login'));
}
```

Comment: I don't want to write the exception, i want to use Auth::user() or Auth::check but it doesn't work unless i put the middleware "auth:sanctum" to that route, but the thing is that if i put the middleware and the user is not authenticated he'll be rejected with a 401 message, or in my case, there are few PUBLIC objects, i want to check wether the user is logged in or not and send the objects accordingly, not rewrite the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem here is the solution to resolve this,

1. Add the "Accept" header to API request and set the value to "application/json"
2. Replace the register method in your App\Exceptions\Handler like this

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

public function register()
{
  $this->renderable(function (AuthenticationException $e, $request) {
    if ($request->is('api/*')) {
        return response()->json([
          'status_code' => 401,
          'success' => false,
          'message' => 'Unauthenticated.'
        ], 401);
    }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also made it with a render function on app/Exceptions/Handler.php :

```php
use Throwable;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;


    public function render($request, Throwable $e) {

        if ($e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            return response()->json([...], 403);
        }
    }
```